# how connect to multiple hosts/databases in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, connection

I'm new in laravel and wondering how could I connect to multiple hosts and multiple databases in Laravel ?

if yes how i could do that dynamically ?

how to add new host connection dynamically ?

how to add new database connection dynamically ?

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
    "host" => "...",
    "database" => "...",
    "username" => "...",
    "password" => "...
]);
```

this is what i had found  but i have no idea how to work further.

Comment: better start reading PHP soon :) http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: thx pha for looking up the dupe, darn this snuffs out your name.

Answer (score 0):

In your database.php, you can add multiple databases.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '',
        'port'      => '',
        'database'  => '',
        'username'  => '',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'mysql2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '',
        'port'      => '',
        'database'  => '',
        'username'  => '',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

In order to use the databases, you can use a variable to use a specific connection, such as:

```
$db1 = DB::connection('mysql');
$db2 = DB::connection('mysql2');
```

Where mysql and mysql2 are the name you've defined your database by in your database.php

To run any raw SQL query, use:

```
$user1 = $db1->table('user_login')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();

$user2 = $db2->table('user_login')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: the main problem is how cloud i do it dynamically ,

Comment: i mean add more connections or retrieve connections from database and set it in  database.php

Comment: there is any way  or method to append new connection in database.php ?

Comment: Honestly, that is never an ideal way to approach a problem. However, if you still want to do that, try following the steps mentioned here: [link] (http://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly). I believe you can modify this a bit and use.